# How to overwrite an entire column with auto increment with SQL

Tags: sql, phpmyadmin, auto-increment

I have a table that is filled with data, however, I would like to overwrite 1 column and fill it with auto-increment values. How would I go about doing this using SQL or phpmyadmin tools?

Thanks.

Comment: For start tell us what is your database ? Then show us your table (columns and datatypes of the columns). And then tell us what is the logic you will order this other columns based on which the increment value will be assigned.

Comment: I would guess it's MySQL. However, which version is it?